# JSON response redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

An `Employee` has many `PartyInvites` and a `Party` has many `PartyInvites`. I would like a controller method to accept a party invite. If controller `PartyInvites` has this (update) method that assigns an `Employee` to a `Party`, which controller is responsible for returning the Party Object?

Maybe I misinterpreted JSON REST API's but if you are working with a specific resource (in this case PartyInvite) then could we return something that the client isn't expecting (a Party). Maybe I'm overthinking this all. But is this what a redirect should be used for to redirect the `PartyInvite` controller to a `Party` controller when the PartyInvite has been accepted?

Comment: You could let the returned json contain also nested information about the party and the employee. The root structure would contain the PartyInvite, but also has a key employee: {} and party: {}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you to create redirects in a RESTful API since it wouldn't be a conventional REST API  anymore.

The client should always get the requested resource with the proper status code back.

However it's possible to redirect the client even in an API. You just have to provide a [3xx Status Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) and a `Location` in your response header. Then the client has to create a new request to the API.

I see only two issues there:

- Normally you would return a `201` status if a resource was created in a RESTful API. But since the client was redirected this status can't be used. (This information can be of course also in the body of the response).
- Every client has to be able to handle redirects. If this API is public you should **explicitly** say in your Documentation that the API redirects to other locations.

The better solution is to embed the `Party` in the `PartyInvite`:

**Example:**

```
{
  "id": 12425124,
  "invitee_count": 15,
  "party": {
    "id": 1252,
    "location": "Wallstreet 10",
    "and_so_on": "..."
  }
}
```

This is the `RESTful` way to return `nested` resources.

But of course you can also use `3xx HTTP Status Codes` to redirect the client to another resource, but be sure that the client understands the response.

Comment: You're saying that I shouldn't redirect and the other guy says that I should redirect. I'll just give you a point because you provided an example at least but I cant mark this as accepted because you haven't provided evidence on why redirects are bad in a RESTful API

Comment: I've added some additional information to the answer. Please check it out and tell me if something is missing or unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Party Invite update can redirect to the specific Party's show controller and return a Party matching the Invite. Of course you can do this with the PartyInvite itself, and the client using the API can adjust accordingly. However, that undermines the RESTfulness of the API