# PHP Is a redirect in API that returns JSON okay?

Tags: php, json, redirect

My API written in PHP returns JSON in an api used by a phone.

Depending on certain paramaters, the PHP file either returns the JSON itself or redirects to a different PHP file that returns similar JSON.

In a browser, the JSON returned directly from the starting file looks identical in form to the JSON returned after the redirect.  However, the phone is not getting any JSON at all if there is a redirect.

This doesn't make sense to me but it's what I'm seeing.  Is it possible for a redirect to mess up a JSON response?

For the record, here is what the JSON looks like in the browser:

```
{"comment":[{"response":"Hello World"}]}
```

**Edit:**

Apparently, redirects in restful APIs are somewhat frowned upon but possible, however, do you have to do something with a status code? This is unfamiliar territory for me.

[JSON response redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33951256/json-response-redirect)

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: If all of the PHP is on the same server, can you include instead of redirect? You will execute the other PHP code without sending a response and waiting for a request. It is much better and doesn't require mucking around with status codes.

Comment: kainaw, I think file_get_contens is the way to go but I'm having trouble with relative paths. I will post a separate question on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do redirects using 307 temporary and 308 permanently codes as stated in the IETF draft https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-hunt-http-rest-redirect-00.html#rfc.section.2.1

Redirection is not the right tool in your case.
As I understand you‘re trying to delegate different endpoints to different files. You should have a look at request routing which happens server side, the client should not have to deal with this.

- https://link.medium.com/Sdp3DyXTHX
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html
- https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/